# What is the equivalent datatype for SQL Server hierarchyid in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, migration, hierarchyid

I have a table in SQL Server which has a column of type `hierarchyid`, the issue is that I can't find the equivalent datatype for this in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.exampleTable{
   id int;
   name varchar(255);
   level hierarchyid not null;
}
```

How would I write the equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You might want to also show some sample data and queries, so we know exactly how you plan to use the `hierarchyid` field.

Answer (score 3):

There is no a direct equivalent datatype in PostgreSQL and without more information on your use case, as Tim correctly says in his comment it is difficult to provide a full answer.

You do have 2 options:

1. You may want to look at the ltree module in the documentation:
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ltree.html
2. Another way hierarchical data is modelled in PostgreSQL is using
   materialized views with recursive common table expressions.